# Maven не добавляет файлы в External Libraries

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

Все depencies добавлены
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.7.0

```
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>dining_api</artifactId>
<version>2.7.0</version>
<name>dining_api</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Однако IDEA не видит файлы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

!!!Все дело в том, что библиотека остается пустой [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбирайте Bundled Maven в настройках
(Настройки -> В поисковой строке Maven home path -> меняем значение на Bundled Maven, как на скрине в ответе)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пошагово опишите действия которые нужно сделать, чтобы добраться до настройки. (Для новичков)

Comment: Настройки -> В поисковой строке Maven home path -> меняем значение на Bundled Maven, как на скрине в ответе

Comment: То что вы тут написали в комментарии ДОЛЖНО быть в вашем ответе, иначе я ставлю тревогу на ваш ответ: "не является ответом", т.к. такой короткий "ответ" можно уместить в комментарий.

Comment: Очень интересно ваше мнение, спасибо, что делитесь им и тратите время на ответ.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Вы уверены, что внимательно прочитали мой комментарий? Даже если да то, пожалуйста, перечитайте и узнайте что я хотел от вас.